# Not able to connect to database when run on Local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, iis-express

I have an asp.net application which runs on IIS express in visual studio. The application runs without any problems in IIS express. However when I switch the project configuration to run on Local IIS, I get the following database error.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
```

This is definitely a connectivity problem as I tried connecting to a remote database and it worked. The problem is accessing a database in the local system.

The strange thing is that the application runs perfectly on visual studio IIS express.

I am using windows authentication and my connection string is as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlConn" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=nga;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I tried modifying the applicationHost configuration according to the following link

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile/

Contents of applicationHosts.config file

```
<applicationPools>
   <add name="DefaultAppPool" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
      <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
   </add>
   <add name="Classic .NET AppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
   <add name=".NET v2.0 Classic" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
   <add name=".NET v2.0" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" />
   <add name=".NET v4.5 Classic" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
   <add name=".NET v4.5" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
   <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
      <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="false" />
   </applicationPoolDefaults>
</applicationPools>
```

That did not help. I was wondering if anyone out there could help me.

Cheers,
Varun

Comment: connection string twice ?

Comment: Thank Varum.  I fixed here : Your connection string is wrong. First use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and get the instance of the database from the login window. SSMS comes with SQL Server. The use the same instance in your connection string. Here is what the Connection String should look like : connectionString="Server=myServerName\myInstanceName; Initial Catalog=nga;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;". Change the instance name (from SSMS login page) and Initial Catalog. The initial Catalog should match a database name in the SSMS explorer after you login.

Comment: I get the same error. tried with <add name="SqlConn" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\Projects\LOCALDB#0EB322B1;Initial Catalog=nga;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: I am able to successfully connect to the database in server management studio. Tried this and it works with IIS express and not with local IIS.  <add name="SqlConn" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=nga;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: Integrated Security = true means you are using a Windows Credential.  So the issue is with the user account on local and remote pc.  Two things must occur. 1) The local and remote PC must have the same group account. 2) The user must be added to the group on both PC.  Usually in a corporate network it uses Group Policies.  And normally users are in Groups by department.  So these two requirements are met.  So you then need to be sure that the SQL Database is setup to use the proper Windows Group Account that allows the user on remote PC access to the database.

Comment: I checked the database properties on SSMS. It allows remote conections

Comment: That property doesn't make a difference when you are using Integrated Security which uses Windows Credentials.  Windows credentials will block remote users from login to PC before SQL Server sees the connection if the Windows Credentials are wrong.

Comment: So how do I fix it. Is there anything I need to to do in SSMS. I am confused because there is no remote PC in this scenario. I am only trying to access a database in my system

Comment: I'm confused also since you said "with IIS express and not with local IIS".  I assumed different computers.  Does IIS express and IIS run with different credentials.  Is it possible that one is running with admin privileges?  I suspect one is started automatically in the services while the other you are manually starting.  The one that is starting in the services automatically probably has admin while other doesn't.  You probably want to get running with no admin account so normal users can use DB.

Comment: The database is residing in my system. Its working when run under IIS express but not when I use Local IIS.

Comment: Is IIS and Local IIS using the same windows user account?  Do you have two operating Systems on same PC?  Are both operating systems using same instance of SQL Server?  I would start by using SQL  Server Management Studio and checking if you can login on both IIS and Local IIS,

Comment: Yes both are using the same user account. Just one operating system.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview.  Look at Non Admin Support.  See if an admin can run under IIS.

Comment: I tried running IIS as admin. No luck. This is annoying. as soon as I change it to IIS express. IT Works !. Local IIS still not working and gives me the same error as in question

Comment: It is my personal laptop and I am the owner of the account. I have another administrator account on this computer. That is all

Comment: Read the FAQ : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-faq

Answer (score -1):

Okay. From the `SqlException` above, it states that

> ..error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

The problem must be in your connection string especially this part where you point to your server instance. `Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;`. Maybe you deleted it or it does not exist.

There are two ways to debug this problem and arrive at a solution:

1. After you build your application, Open View > Server Explorer or simply use Ctrl+Alt+S to open the Server Explorer dialog on the left side of Visual Studio. Under Data Connections, check if you will see your model name, e.g "SqlConn". VS will try to open a connection to `(localdb)`. If it fails, then you can be sure that `(localdb)\Projects` instance got deleted. You can either use `(localdb)\v11.0` or recreate `Projects` instance using SqlLocalDB utility.

2.Here is a link to [SqlLocalDB Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility). Use this command`sqllocaldb c Projects 11.0`.

For further assistance on this problem, you can check with the accepted answer on this [Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007913/the-specified-localdb-instance-does-not-exist)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it does not exist, how does it work with IIS express. I did check. It exists and works like a charm with IIS express. I am having problems only when I change it to Local IIS. And I am able to log in to the database using server management studio.

Comment: Answer to the 1).  It works with my original connection string in the question

Answer (score -1):

You just need to set "**Listen All**" to yes in the SQL Server Configuration Manager:

[image]