# cannot open database "dataBaseName" requested by the login

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application published to be hosted on IIS 10.

When I open the application through the browser, the following error shows up:

> Cannot open database "dataBaseName" requested by the login 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-GP7EJHU$'

Connection string:

```
Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=SOO;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

The `DESKTOP-GP7EJHU$` is my computer name and SQL Server doesn't have a user with this name.

Where can I configure the login to connect in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to login sql server without username and password, you should add IIS ApplicationPool's user in sql server logins. following links may help you:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/477152/how-do-i-grant-iis-apppool-orchard-access-to-sql-server-2012-developer
- https://engram404.net/grant-sql-permissions-to-iis-apppool-user/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2015/04/14/how-to-add-the-applicationpoolidentity-to-a-sql-server-login/
- [Not able to connect to database when run on Local IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742555/not-able-to-connect-to-database-when-run-on-local-iis)

Comment: The second link has successfully solved my issue. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This part of the [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) tells SQL Server to connect as the current user:

```
Trusted_Connection=True;
```

You can replace it with:

```
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```